# error C2259: 'CSceneObjMediator' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am getting the following error:

> error C2259: 'CSceneObjMediator' : cannot instantiate abstract class

for the following code:

```
    CSceneObjMediator* CSceneObjServerMgr::CreateSceneObjMediator()
{
    uint32 uId = GetobjId();

    CSceneObjServer* pObj = PPE_NEW_T (CSceneObjServer, MEMCATEGORY_GENERAL, "")(uId);
    CSceneObjMediator* pMediator = PPE_NEW_T(CSceneObjMediator, MEMCATEGORY_GENERAL, "")(pObj);
    return pMediator;
}
```

And the other following error:

> error C2259: 'CSceneObjDictator' : cannot instantiate abstract class

for the following code:

```
    CSceneObjDictator* CSceneObjServerMgr::CreateSceneObjDictator()
{
    uint32 uId = GetobjId();
    CSceneObjServer* pObj = PPE_NEW_T (CSceneObjServer, MEMCATEGORY_GENERAL, "")(uId);
    CSceneObjDictator* pDictator = PPE_NEW_T (CSceneObjDictator, MEMCATEGORY_GENERAL, "")(pObj);
    return pDictator;
}
```

**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: most probably your macro ```PPE_NEW_T``` tries to instantiate an abstract class, which ```CSceneObjDictator``` just happens to be.

Comment: What are these classes? Are they abstract base classes? Or have you (or someone) forgotten to implement the abstract functions?

Comment: ```CSceneObjDictator``` seems to be an abstract interface, so you have to instantiate an object of a class (for example ```CSceneObjDictatorImpl```) that inherits ```CSceneObjDictator``` and implements its abstract virtual methods. Then you ```return PPE_NEW_T (CSceneObjDictatorImpl, MEMCATEGORY_GENERAL, "")(pObj);```

Comment: And the errors should tell you which methods have not been declared (not implemented would wait until link-time). The listing might not appear if you use the error list window - Not sure on this point, I always use the console (The View->Output menu item).

Comment: Here is the link to download the source

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nEwj71Z6ZWGd4jiPqJuh7YKWvyZhZUM_

Comment: Password to decompress: “极·致·轻”，没有如果，你就是英雄！车库源码（http://src.cool）与您共同进步！

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us *in the question itself!*

Comment: According to the [Compiler Error C2259](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2259?view=vs-2019). An abstract class cannot be instantiated by definition. In order to use this class, you must create a concrete subclass which implements all virtual functions of the class.